# Java Compiler Error "class, interface, or enum expected" but I cannot find any of the common causes of this error

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to use git commit to commit my changes to a repo, but when I do, I keep getting a 'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException' with the caused by statement being 'Caused by: com.google.googlejavaformat.java.FormatterException: 5:9: error: class, interface, or enum expected'

I understand some of the common causes of this error are too many/too few curly braces, or placing a method outside the class, but I cannot seem to find such an error here.

```
package *********;

import java.util.UUID;

public record PaymentLinkUpdateDTO(UUID paymentDeclineID,
    String paymentIntentID,
    String paymentMethodId,
    String customerMethodID,
    String paymentLinkID) {
}
```

A few things to note. 1. I did not write this code segment, it is just in the project I am on. 2. PaymentLinkUpdateDTO is used in 30 different spots but from what I can tell it is properly used/placed each time. 3. I removed the package name for privacy reasons. Error code is below, with package name again removed.

```
Step 'removeUnusedImports' found problem in '****/PaymentLinkUpdateDTO.java':
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor375.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.java.GoogleJavaFormatStep$State.lambda$constructRemoveUnusedFunction$4(GoogleJavaFormatStep.java:211)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.java.GoogleJavaFormatStep$State.lambda$createRemoveUnusedImportsOnly$2(GoogleJavaFormatStep.java:188)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterFunc.apply(FormatterFunc.java:32)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStepImpl$Standard.format(FormatterStepImpl.java:82)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStep$Strict.format(FormatterStep.java:88)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.Formatter.compute(Formatter.java:230)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.PaddedCell.calculateDirtyState(PaddedCell.java:203)
        at com.diffplug.spotless.PaddedCell.calculateDirtyState(PaddedCell.java:190)
        at com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.SpotlessTaskImpl.processInputFile(SpotlessTaskImpl.java:102)
        at com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.SpotlessTaskImpl.performAction(SpotlessTaskImpl.java:88)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:236)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:204)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:181)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: com.google.googlejavaformat.java.FormatterException: 5:9: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.FormatterException.fromJavacDiagnostics(FormatterException.java:51)
        at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.RemoveUnusedImports.parse(RemoveUnusedImports.java:262)
        at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.RemoveUnusedImports.removeUnusedImports(RemoveUnusedImports.java:219)
        ... 129 more
```

UPDATE:
I deleted my project, rebooted my machine (mac), created a new directory, cloned the master branch, created a new local branch, and now am able to commit some changes.
I don't think this is a permanent solution; I am guessing an underlying problem still exists.

UPDATE 2:
Apparently the problem is caused when I try and commit changes made to certain areas of the project. For example, I want to modify one class in the main code section and the error pops up, but I can modify a docker-compose file with no issues.

Comment: Looks like `com.diffplug.spotless` cannot handle records yet. Disable the plugin or upgrade

Comment: I tried upgrading the plugin but this did not resolve the error.

Comment: Then I see two options: a) disable the plugin or b) don't use records in your code

Comment: I can look into disabling the plugin temporarily but neither of those two options seem viable long term unfortunately. I am simply the low man on the totem poll so disabling the plugin on an enterprise level project is above my pay grade.

Comment: Third option: wait until the plugin supports records. Fourth option: contribute code to the plugin so it can support records. It's [hacktober](https://hacktoberfest.com/) after all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a java version that does not support (or support not enabled for) Java "record".

The error is:

```
   class, interface, or enum expected
```

But it finds a record.

They were delivered in Java 14 as a preview feature. See [this](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8246771).

Comment: I want to agree with you, but the program runs with using record. I can do other tasks with the code, I just cant commit to a local branch

Comment: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/977 Did you try upgrading to this version?

Comment: I have not yet but will try tomorrow when I get to the office and let you know. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I do not see any place to change the googleJavaFormat version. The only version for spotless I see and have access to is in my gradle.properties file 'spotlessVersion=6.10.0'

Comment: did you try 6.11.0? https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.diffplug.gradle.spotless

Comment: AFAIK, java records are supported by spotless. https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues

Comment: Try asking this at https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues

Comment: Turns out that for some reason when I opened intellij that it reverted me back to an older version of java, one that did not support records. I fixed this problem and now the overall issues is fixed. Long story short, I am dumber than I thought.

Comment: Never say that. It happens to the best of us. :-)